# Uniform Convergence of $f_n(x)= \cos^nx(1-\cos^nx)$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

$$ \text{Is } f_n(x)= \cos^nx(1-\cos^nx) \text{ uniformly convergent on } \left[0,\frac{ \pi}{2}\right]  \text{ ? }$$
I solved the question for pointwise convergence and found that
$$  f_n(x)\to 0  \space \space \forall \space x \text{ on } \left[0,\frac{\pi}{2} \right] $$
Now i have to show that the series of functions are not uniformly convergent to zero . 
My question is that what value should I take for $$ x $$ such that it belongs to the  $$ \left[0,\frac{ \pi}{2}\right] $$ and such that the function is not uniformly convergent .

Comment: Do a function study (by derivation).

Comment: can you elaborate ? I did not get it .

Comment: Do you know variation table ?

Comment: Let $x_n$ be such that $cos x_n = (1-1/n)$, and see what $f_n(x_n)$ does.

Comment: you mean function analysis by first order derivative test ? @lucas

Comment: Yes. Fix $n$ and make this study to prove there exists $a > 0$ and $x_n$  for all $n$ such that $|f(x_n)| > a $ kimchi gives directly $(x_n)$ but you had to find it (although it can be noted the expression of $f_n$ is symmetrical).

Comment: @kimchilover You may post this as an answer.

Comment: In my solution manual they got $$ a = \frac{1}{4} $$ so thats what I cannot figure out that what value of x gives that .

Comment: You just need to know there exists such a $x_n$ for all $f_n$ (it is not the same for all $n$).

Comment: Actually, my method is general but quite painful. The other ones are more clever (e.g. IVT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Your $x$ should depend upon $n$ if you want to show non-uniform convergence this way.

You could e.g. use the IVT to show that for any $n$ there is $x$ (depending upon $n$) so that $\cos^n(x)=1/2$.

Comment: Is IVT intermediate value theorem ?

Comment: @Aqua yes, indeed.

Comment: ok , thanks a lot .